# JOOQ-How to generalize database operations

Tags: jooq

I'm writing insert, updates methods and trying to use generic arguments as method parameters. Following is the code that I've written so far in Ceylon and it compiles well.

```
shared void insert<R>(DSLContext ctx, Table<R&Record> table, Set<TableField<R&Record, Object>> fields, Set<Object> values){
    ctx.insertInto(table).columns(fields).values(values).execute();
}
```

I would like to pass the fields and values as part of method call. I've a class generated by JOOQ as:

```
public class TblGuest extends TableImpl<TblGuestRecord> {
    public final TableField<TblGuestRecord, Integer> id ....
    public final TableField<TblGuestRecord, String> guestName...
}
```

As it is evident that the fields have different Generic parameters for TableField, I would like to know if there is a way to add these parameters in a HashSet ... `Set<TableField<GuestRecord,Object>> fields = HashSet<TableField<GuestRecord,Object>>();`

Of course, adding any `TableField<GuestRecord,????>` apart from `TableField<GuestRecord,Object>` will result in compilation exception. But is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Using wildcards is more appropriate rather than putting a lot of Generic Param types. The following code works as expected:

```
shared void insert<R>(DSLContext ctx, Table<R&Record> table, Set<TableField<R&Record, out Object>> fields, Set<Object> values){
            ctx.insertInto(table).columns(fields).values(values).execute();       
}


shared void update<R>(DSLContext ctx, Table<R&Record> table, JMap<TableField<R&Record, out Object>, Object> map){
    ctx.update(table).set(map).execute();
}
```

And the caller can have an instance of HashSet/HashMap as :

```
JMap<TableField<GuestRecord, out Object>, Object> map = JHashMap<TableField<GuestRecord, out Object>, Object>();

Set<TableField<GuestRecord,out Object>> fields = HashSet<TableField<GuestRecord, out Object>>();
```

Comment: I agree that this looks like a very reasonable case for using use-site variance.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to achieve it by changing the Generic params of Set to `Set<TableField<R&Record, Object>|TableField<R&Record, JString>|TableField<R&Record, JInteger>> fields`. And creating a HashSet with the same generic types in the caller. That means, in order to write an insert/update method with generic arguments using JOOQ, one must parameterize all the type arguments with the unique field types created in JOOQ table classes. However, is it the best way/right way to do it?